# Como fazer replace múltiplo utilizando variável como primeiro parametro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Quando desejo fazer um replace em todas as ocorrencias de uma string eu faço dessa forma:

```
var ola= "ola mundo ola mundo";

ola = ola.replace(/ola/g, "xxx");
```

Resultado: "xxx mundo xxx mundo";

Porém desejo utilizar uma variável ao invés de colocar a palavra explícita, dessa forma:

```
var ola= "ola mundo ola mundo";
var variavel= "ola";

ola = ola.replace(/variavel/g, "xxx");
```

Só que não sei como concatenar isso para funcionar. Já tentei de algumas formas e não funcionou.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nesse caso tens de criar uma expressão regular usando o construtor para gerar o objeto RegExp:

> [new RegExp(variavel [, flag])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Exemplo:

```
var string = "ola mundo ola mundo";
var variavel = "ola";
var regexp = new RegExp(variavel, 'g');
string = string.replace(regexp, "xxx");
alert(string); // dá "xxx mundo xxx mundo"
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldrynpsf/**

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var ola = "ola mundo ola mundo";
var variavel = "ola";

var re = new RegExp(variavel, 'g');
ola = ola.replace(re, 'xxx');

alert(ola); // xxx mundo xxx mundo
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yd2h7v2w/)</kbd>

Ao invés de usar `/regex/` você pode criar um novo objeto [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), dando a possibilidade de passar uma *string* ou uma variável.

```
new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```

Onde *pattern* é a expressão regular (*nesse caso será uma variável*) a ser usada e *flags* indica os *modificadores* a serem usados, por exemplo o `g` *global match*.